# How to pass interface to method that have lot of arguments

Tags: go, go-interface

I had written a lazy code to demonstrate the issue I am having to implement interfaces. I have methods M1, M2 that take struct X as an argument and have a type of struct Y. I wanted all these methods to be implemented by a single interface I. The issue is the method M that implements the interface I needs to be aware of the arguments that are required to be passed to the child methods (M1,M2). I get an error: `<argument name> used as a value` when I pass multiple arguments in M

```
type Y struct {
 a int
}

type X struct {
 a int
}

(y *Y) func M1(x X) struct {
 return y.a+x.a
}

(y *Y) func M2(x X) struct {
 return y.a*x.a
}

type I interface {
 M1(x X)
 M2(x X)
}

func M(i I, x X) {
 fmt.println(i.M1(x)) //returns an error i.M1(x) used as a value
 fmt.println(i.M2(x)) //returns an error i.M2(x) used as a value
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that cause `<argument name> used as a value` error in your example is that functions that form interface `I` are declared to have no return value:

```
type I interface {
 M1(x X)
 M2(x X)
}
```

Surely you can't pass function-call as argument of `Println` if the function returns nothing: `fmt.println(i.M1(x))`. Change the interface declaration in your example to return something (and a few more fixes*):

```
type Y struct {
 a int
}

type X struct {
 a int
}

func(y *Y) M1(x X) int {
 return y.a+x.a
}

func(y *Y) M2(x X) int {
 return y.a*x.a
}

type I interface {
 M1(x X) int
 M2(x X) int
}

func M(i I, x X) {
 fmt.Println(i.M1(x))
 fmt.Println(i.M2(x))
}
```

**<kbd>[`playground`](https://play.golang.org/p/E17V2rSIXs6)</kbd>**

*) change `M1` & `M2` to return `int` instead of `struct` and fix syntax for function declaration with receiver